# Proof with parallelogram inside a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

[image]

Prove that $PBRS$ is a parallelogram.

(Note: $P$ and $Q$ are respectively the middles of the sides $AB$ and $CD$)

Now the corrections give the following method:

- $PBQD$ is a parallelogram
- $BR \parallel PS$
- $\triangle BPR \cong \triangle SRP$ (SAS) $\Longrightarrow$ $\angle BPR=\angle SRP$ (alternate interior angles) $\Longrightarrow BP\parallel RS$
- In quadrilateral $PBRS$, opposite sides are equal in length, so $PBRS$ is a parallelogram.

Since I find the first line a bit vague, is there another way to approach that part of the problem that also uses the congruent triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another proof:
$$
\triangle ADP\cong \triangle CBQ 
$$
because of SAS, because $|AD|=|BC|$, $|AP|=\frac 12|AB|=\frac 12 |CD|=|CQ|$ and $\angle DAP=\angle DAB=\angle BCD=\angle BCQ$. This implies $\angle ADP=\angle CBQ$. Now $DP$ and $BQ$ are parallel because $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel.
Now, use the second part of the proof you gave.

Comment: What SAS did you use in the first congruence?

Comment: @user3761304, edited my answer